# How do I reindex catalogue on Magento 2? 'reindex' dropdown not available

Tags: magento2, reindex

New products are not appearing on the live page. I understand I have to reindex the catalogue and clear cache for them to appear.

> `Selecting: system > Index Management`

When setting all to 'update on save' the boxes are red and do not have a current date/time.

When setting all to 'update by schedule' the boxes are green and do have today's date/time but this does not make a difference to the live site - I'm not sure of the difference between these two options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to CLI, run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` then clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify magento 2 does not allow you to reindex from the admin without an extension. Therefore you have to use the command line as the other answer suggests.

The different in modes is as follows

> Update on Save - index tables are updated immediately after the dictionary data is changed.
>
> Update by Schedule - index tables are updated by cron job according to the configured schedule.

To learn more about indexers go here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Here is an extension soon which gives you option to index from admin https://github.com/magepal/magento2-reindex

Answer (score 0):

Please find difference between reindex on save and reindex on schedule

**Reindex On Save** - The Reindex will take place in real time when a change is saved in backend. It will be fine for small websites with a few admin users.

**Reindex On Schedule** - Reindex will be scheduled to take place via cronjobs accordingly. It will be suitable for stores with huge data and many admin users. If you have set reindex to occur every one hour, if you are making any change in the backend your change will be applied in the frontend within a maximum period of 1 hour.

**indexer:reindex** - When you want to reindex all indexers we can use this command.Ex: If a reindex gets locked we can reset the indexer and use this command to reindex all indexers.

Both **Reindex On Save** and **Reindex On Schedule** can be used to update the index of changes stores. You can choose between the two based on your store size and frequency of changes made to products.

Please make sure your **cronjob** is running to make sure reindex by schedule works.